# How to make backgroundworker work in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

I am pretty new to programming and WPF architecture. I have a WPF application which uses a backgroundworker class. However, it always throws the error "the calling thread must be sta because many ui components require this". I need to add  the STAThread attribute my main method. But I am not sure how to do this.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.backgroundWorker1 = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();           

            InitializeBackgroundWorker();
            Thread.CurrentThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            tabItemList.CollectionChanged += this.TabCollectionChanged;
        }
}


 private void InitializeBackgroundWorker()
        {
            backgroundWorker1.DoWork +=
                new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted +=
                new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(
            backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
            backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged +=
                new ProgressChangedEventHandler(
            backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
        }

        // This event handler is where the actual, 
        // potentially time-consuming work is done. 
        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender,
            DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            // Get the BackgroundWorker that raised this event.
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

            // Assign the result of the computation 
            // to the Result property of the DoWorkEventArgs 
            // object. This is will be available to the  
            // RunWorkerCompleted eventhandler.
            //e.Result = AddTabitem((int)e.Argument, worker, e);
            AddTabitem((string)e.Argument, worker, e);
        }

 void AddTabitem(string filePath, BackgroundWorker worker, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
//This line which throws error "the calling thread must be sta because many ui components require this"
                RichTextBox mcRTB = new RichTextBox();
                rtbList.Add(mcRTB);
}
```

Comment: apart from agreeing with demoncodemonkey's answer you should look into the "Task" class.

Comment: There is almost no reason why you should even THINK about using `BackgroundWorker`. For one thing, if you use MVVM/Binding, you would have automatic UI thread marshaling. For another, you should use `Task.Run` for any CPU bound computation and asynchronous Task I/O for any I/O bound operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got to set the ApartmentState **before** the thread is started.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2005/04/07/406341.aspx

To set the apartment state on your WPF App,
add the `[STAThread]` attribute to your application, like [this](http://ludovic.chabant.com/devblog/2010/04/20/writing-a-custom-main-method-for-wpf-applications/):

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Window1 window = new Window1();
        App app = new App();
        app.Run(window);
    }
}
```

Comment: When I add this part of the code it throws an error saying 'Editor.App' already defines a member called 'Main' with the same parameter types. And I do see that there exsists a Main() in App.g.cs and I also see that [System.STAThreadAttribute()] is added before Main(). So why does my program still throw errors?

Comment: Sorry I missed the step where I had to change the application’s build action from “Application Definition” to “Page”. Even after doing so when I run the app it still throws "the calling thread must be sta because many ui components require this". I added the AddTabItem code in my questio to show where exactly it errors. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Using this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        ...// your code here.
    })); solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

Nuked my bit about STAThread, as this isn't your problem.

After reviewing your updated background worker code, you are attempting to update the UI from the background worker thread. This won't work, as you've experienced. You have a couple options:

1) Instead of directly updating that RichTextBox, instead update a variable that you have databinded to that property you are updating. See this article for an overview on databinding, as you have stated that you are new to WPF:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx

2) Use Invoke instead of directly setting the property. You might need to do this for option 1 anyhow. This is probably your most direct quick fix. Here is a good reason the WPF Dispatcher which is what you will need to do this invoking business: http://tech.pro/tutorial/800/working-with-the-wpf-dispatcher

It would work like this:
     mcRTB.Dispatcher.Invoke(
          System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
          new Action(
            delegate()
            {
              mcRTB.Text = "hello";
            }
        ));

The above is for changing a property. You can adapt that to invoke your rtbList's .Add method as well.

3) Want to avoid invoking? Use your background worker's reports progress! This event fires when you tell it to within the BW, and then you can do some work on the main UI thread without having to worry about invoking stuff.

When you initialize your BW, tack this in there:

```
backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChanged EventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
```

Then in your call back that you make (or have autocreated for you with the +=), you can do work on your UI thread. You can tell your BW to report some progress by doing this:

```
// the int in the first parameter is arbitrary
// the object can be any object. This is how you pass actual data to your call back
backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(1,new object())
```

Here is a good read on reporting progress:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It gives an error, Arrtribute 'STAThread' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'method' declarations.

Comment: You're right, it's supposed to go the main entry point method. See demoncodemonkey's answer for the correct placement. Still, you shouldn't be needing a STAThread to make a background worker do its thing. Can you post all your background worker related code?

Comment: Added the remaining code which shows the background worker in detail.

Comment: you are correct, updating the UI from the backgroundworker thread was the problem, using Dispatch.invoke do solve my problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to be of help! If this solved your problem, could you accept this answer? Thanks!